# How to filter out whole groups using dplyr, that have columns satisfying a particular property?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

Using mtcars as an example: assume I wanted to remove the groups based on "carb" column if any of the observations within a group had "disp" less than 100. I know how to do this using base R:

```
data(mtcars)
xx <- split (mtcars, as.factor (mtcars$carb))
xx <- xx[sapply (xx, function(x) min(x$disp) > 100)] 
xx <- do.call (rbind, xx)
```

but is there a more elegant way to do this using dplyr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `carb` and remove groups which have any value less than 100 for `disp`.

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% filter(all(disp > 100))
#Or
#mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% filter(!any(disp < 100))


#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
# 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
# 4  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
# 5  17.8     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
# 6  16.4     8  276.   180  3.07  4.07  17.4     0     0     3     3
# 7  17.3     8  276.   180  3.07  3.73  17.6     0     0     3     3
# 8  15.2     8  276.   180  3.07  3.78  18       0     0     3     3
# 9  10.4     8  472    205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4
#10  10.4     8  460    215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4
#11  14.7     8  440    230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
#12  13.3     8  350    245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4
#13  15.8     8  351    264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4
#14  19.7     6  145    175  3.62  2.77  15.5     0     1     5     6
#15  15       8  301    335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
```

Comment: This.  Also will work using `all()` inside the call to `filter()`.  I typically end up explicitly calling the `dplyr::filter()` function too (since `stats::filter()` interferes for me):  `mtcars %>% group_by(carb) %>% dplyr::filter(all(disp > 100))`

Comment: @chemdork123 Yes, this can be made to work with `all` as well `any`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by grouping observations by `carb`, creating new variable `min_disp` that shows the minimum displacement per group, and then filtering `min_disp` > 100:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(carb) %>%
  mutate(min_disp = min(disp)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(min_disp > 100)
```

(I recommend running the code step-by-step so that you can see what's going on)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mtcars)[, .SD[all(disp > 100)], carb]
```